# Editing web.config under tag that contains dot

Tags: powershell

I want to add a new key-value pair in web.config with ps. However, the tag I wanted to add is under <web.server> tag. For example, the tag before web.server is location and how I added a new line under location tag is

```
 $webConfig.configuration.location.AppendChild($newElement) | Out-Null
```

and that worked. But, when I wanted to add new line under <web.server>, the code below throws null valued expression:

```
 $webConfig.configuration.location.system.web.AppendChild($newElement) | Out-Null
```

I tried parentheses with no luck. How can i do this?

Comment: Use quotes around the member: `.'web.server'.`

Comment: You can use `$webConfig.SelectSingleNode('//web.server')`